# Programatically create table header in C# Razor Pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am attempting to automate the HTML generation of a table header using Razor Pages with .NET 6. It has quite a few columns, and I would be spending too much time typing them out. My issue is that every column header is named `displayValue`. My current, and closest, implementation is defined below:

```
<tr>
            @{
                // Get list of properties associated with the Procedure model
                var properties = typeof(Models.Procedure).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                var varName = "";

                // Loop over each property and generate a table header for it
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    // Use the zero-th index of a list "Procedure" attempting to replace
                    // @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure[0].<property>) with
                    // @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => displayValue)
                    var displayValue = property.GetValue(Model.Procedure[0]);
                    varName = property.Name;
                    <th>
                        @if (Model.SortOrder == varName)
                        {
                            routeData["sortOrder"] = $"{varName}_desc";
                            <i class="bi-sort-up"></i>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            routeData["sortOrder"] = varName;
                            <i class="bi-sort-down"></i>
                        }
                        <a asp-page="./Index" asp-all-route-data=@routeData class="nav-link p-0 d-inline">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => displayValue)
                        </a>
                    </th>
                }
            }
</tr>
```

[A visual description of the issue here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh6br.png)

I am afraid that I am unable to reference the `displayValue` variable in the `HTML.DisplayNameFor` function, yet it has the same value as any `model.Procedure[0].<property>` value. Is there some small syntax issue I am neglecting, am I even going about this in the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to display column names @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)

Comment: To customize the name add the attribution [Display(Name = "First Name")]

Comment: You probably want something like `var name = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName ?? property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name ?? property.Name; ... <a ...>@name</a>`. But, personally I would just define the table explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the name of properties?Is `property.Name` what you want?

Comment: @YiyiYou `property.Name` is almost what I want, but it doesn't have the proper display name for the HTML element, e.x.: `SomePropertyName` would not display as `Some Long Property Name` I defined with the tag.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you for your help. After thinking about it some more, trying to programmatically create the columns will create more trouble than it is worth trying to match the table headers with the body. I'll be defining the table explicitly.